# Slowdown of pi calculation when Timer is used

Tags: chapel

The following code is my code for calculating pi = 3.1415... approximately using [**this**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) formula:

```
use Time;
var timer = new Timer();

config const n = 10**9;
var x = 0.0, s = 0.0;

// timer.start();                                     // [1]_____

for k in 0 .. n {
    s = ( if k % 2 == 0 then 1.0 else -1.0 );  // (-1)^k
    x += s / ( 2.0 * k + 1.0 );
}

// timer.stop();                                      // [2]_____
// writeln( "time = ", timer.elapsed() );             // [3]_____

   writef( "pi (approx) = %30.20dr\n", x * 4 );
// writef( "pi (exact)  = %30.20dr\n", pi );          // [4]_____
```

When the above code is compiled as `chpl --fast test.chpl` and executed as `time ./a.out`, then it runs with **~4 seconds** as

```
pi (approx) =         3.14159265458805059268

real    0m4.334s
user    0m4.333s
sys     0m0.006s
```

On the other hand, if I uncomment Lines `[1--3]` ( to use `Timer` ), the program runs much slower with **~10 seconds** as

```
time = 10.2284
pi (approx) =         3.14159265458805059268

real    0m10.238s
user    0m10.219s
sys     0m0.018s
```

The same slow-down occurs when I uncomment only Line `[4]` ( to print the built-in value of pi, with Lines `[1-3]` kept commented out ):

```
pi (approx) =         3.14159265458805059268
pi (exact)  =         3.14159265358979311600

real    0m10.144s
user    0m10.141s
sys     0m0.009s
```

So I'm wondering why this slow-down occurs...

Am I missing something in the above code (e.g., wrong usage of `Timer`)?

My environment is OSX10.11 + chapel-1.16 installed via homebrew.
More details are below:

```
$ printchplenv --anonymize
CHPL_TARGET_PLATFORM: darwin
CHPL_TARGET_COMPILER: clang
CHPL_TARGET_ARCH: native
CHPL_LOCALE_MODEL: flat
CHPL_COMM: none
CHPL_TASKS: qthreads
CHPL_LAUNCHER: none
CHPL_TIMERS: generic
CHPL_UNWIND: none
CHPL_MEM: jemalloc
CHPL_MAKE: make
CHPL_ATOMICS: intrinsics
CHPL_GMP: gmp
CHPL_HWLOC: hwloc
CHPL_REGEXP: re2
CHPL_WIDE_POINTERS: struct
CHPL_AUX_FILESYS: none

$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

---

**Update**

Following the suggestions, I installed Chapel from source by following [this](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/usingchapel/QUICKSTART.html) and [this](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/usingchapel/chplenv.html#chapel-configuration-file) pages and adding `CHPL_TARGET_COMPILER=gnu` to `~/.chplconfig` (before running `make`). Then, all the three cases above ran with ~4 seconds. So, the problem may be related to clang on OSX10.11. According to the comments, newer OSX (>= 10.12) does not have this problem, so it may be simply sufficient to upgrade to newer OSX/clang (>= 9.0). FYI, the updated environment info (with GNU) is as follows:

```
$ printchplenv --anonymize
CHPL_TARGET_PLATFORM: darwin
CHPL_TARGET_COMPILER: gnu +
CHPL_TARGET_ARCH: native
CHPL_LOCALE_MODEL: flat
CHPL_COMM: none
CHPL_TASKS: qthreads
CHPL_LAUNCHER: none
CHPL_TIMERS: generic
CHPL_UNWIND: none
CHPL_MEM: jemalloc
CHPL_MAKE: make
CHPL_ATOMICS: intrinsics
CHPL_GMP: none
CHPL_HWLOC: hwloc
CHPL_REGEXP: none
CHPL_WIDE_POINTERS: struct
CHPL_AUX_FILESYS: none
```

Comment: Are you sure you used --fast in all cases?  I consistently get around 4 seconds in all 3 cases you described, but 11 seconds if I leave off --fast.

Comment: Yes, I have just re-tried all the three cases with --fast option, but it is reproducible on my mac (by the way, I used -o a.out in the question, but this did not affect the result). If this is not reproducible on other environments, it might be due to my own environment...

Comment: I seem to be seeing a slowdown similar to those reported by this question (though of slightly different magnitudes) on my Mac.  No theories as to why, though.  The uncommented lines should add some overhead, but I wouldn't expect them to add seconds / double the execution time.

Comment: I am also seeing the reported slowdowns on OS X 10.11 + Chapel 1.17 pre-release (05fe3d5). ~4 seconds -> ~8 seconds when uncommented.

Comment: @roygvib - what version of clang are you using?

Comment: If I switch CHPL_TARGET_COMPILER from 'clang' to 'gnu', the disparity goes away.  I suspect there's something funny going on at the clang compilation level...

Comment: @bencray I tried "clang --version", and it says clang-800.0.42.1. I've also added the output of printchplenv in the question above.

Comment: @Brad Setting "export CHPL_TARGET_COMPILER=gnu" and compiling the code the same way gives "$CHPL_HOME/modules/internal/String.chpl:61: error: Cannot find module or enum" on my Mac for some reason.. I also tried completely removing Time related things, but adding the last writef() statement shows the problem again (and replacing "pi" to a literal like 3.14 gives the same problem). So maybe I should use Linux :-)

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified that I am building from source using the master branch from GitHub in my experiments.  The homebrew-based installation of Chapel currently only supports the clang target compiler out of the box, so I believe you'd need to download and build from source to reproduce my experiment (though note that you can download the official 1.16.0 release sources and build it as documented here: https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/usingchapel/QUICKSTART.html rather than working from master as I am).

Comment: @Brad Thanks, I've re-installed from source (after adding ~/.chplconfig that contains "CHPL_TARGET_COMPILER=gnu", following https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/usingchapel/chplenv.html#chapel-configuration-file), and then all the three cases ran with ~4 seconds also on my Mac! So clang seems to be doing something... Thanks very much anyway :)

Comment: I think the next step in diagnosing this, if one were interested, might be to look at the assembly generated by clang to see how it differs between versions of the program.  But I'm not sure I'm sufficiently motivated to do so unless it matters greatly to someone.  I have checked the C code generated by the Chapel compiler for the various versions and am not seeing anything that would obviously cause this type of change.

Comment: Also, @bencray suggested that users of newer OS X versions (e.g., 10.13) weren't able to reproduce this, and I'm guessing that they have newer versions of clang as well.  So maybe the issue has fixed itself and we just need to upgrade?

Comment: Yes, I will probably upgrade to newer OSX (after the recent "anyone-can-login-as-root" problem is fixed ;).

Comment: When I tried to reproduce this I was using OSX 10.12 and clang 9.0.  It looks like the clang version difference explains it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I missing something in the above code (e.g., wrong usage of Timer)?

No, you're not missing anything and are using `Timer` (and Chapel) in a completely reasonable way.  From my own experimentation (which confirms yours and is noted in the comments under your question), this looks to be a back-end compiler issue rather than a fundamental problem in Chapel or your use of it.

Answer (score 1):

### `[--fast]` reduces run-time checks, yet [not the issue may re-run here](https://tio.run/##rVVtb5swEP6eX3GqVAmSYgzYFNp1UjT147qqL9KmLqsQOC0qgQhom2lqf/qys4GkDaRKut4HDGf74e55zufwNpiKZD4HtPtCwEU8EYc9@fUQ5FDiVw5HkIpHNZNrejWpHmGWjuMbORQlpLjMov2@Xy1YmIQpcI4Sugez6qVjybDMJvH3AwjkGEIuguQQ1ptpwlW1ZXStrNdaUk2TxzwuhSb/Cvr2iOqhWCBFGeSl9ibGGlirQuwpMLMP7zYJRiuw4cn18dfTix/XZ5cnFfA4y@EO4hQoEIJy/FlQUgDSrkE8xvldsOEIRYDyVqRgISsiQdkNa8kP/kUzLP3X3QJgBoMjREE/2LiujzgDqHaoNU91amazA2MJkqQOhxAMppEjiCJto1h6GxHSjqi3GZWY6xP0zfcVQjbdug4UrD1aAqq6TFINdiQqCrSzV@OLJJgWItL0tQUrsZyXRdXgjRFuGoMWTKd5NtMRddehxKZR/jNFfIZEzWrUWrGN9w0xONQPD2YdWTdPq4hiFoSlDquIONVOTiKy0QrnZl8NxvYGV4YxDopyJIGHJ6DOC8jz0mgpW5YwqFuReIY9R7kPAHzCPRsK5b8sRN74PcL2/dp//rsgjZ8S7lu1/8vpJRS3QY5@nxGXw65yH8/iEntlhG76ISnJExZmk4lISxEtCXutY2MOsZjFfdvljHse5VS@e8tdL5K3OOHcaSdvOYR5DPvA88b2ubo14BkGpgFIkMDLIsJD@808hzSL8bTrHVz6Hu/g0iHU@TguGypBcanCNO5T4zWhdZFw4lDL9lZcju1/EOGMONztJJyy/a0I//Q@wnkn4Yz4ncXbit8lHmUd8TPiLQppRWG7W2HPX6fwf8q8RmW8Neq7alDdUGHxut3LFsHIPsMmsbnWrkd93@nU2vYIzrW5sl1iM7fNFVJlsQ6q3DcaS9@cz/@G4yS4KeZV9v8A)

Kindly may also note, how big are setup/operation add-on overheads,
brought in just for educational purposes
( to experiment with concurrent-processing ), that make the **`forall`**-constructor equipped with <kbd>**Atomics**</kbd> `.add()` method, accrue a way much higher overheads, than a concurrent-processing allow to gain, as there is so tiny computation inside the `[PAR]`-enabled fraction of the process ( [*ref.* **newly re-formulated Amdahl's Law**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) on these too thin **`[PAR]`**-gains v/s indeed too high add-on overheads to the **`[SEQ]`**-costs ).

An exemplary message.

```
use Time;
var timer = new Timer();

config const n = 10**9;
         var s = 0.0, x = 0.0;
         var AtomiX: atomic real;                           // [AtomiX]______
             AtomiX.write( 0.0 );                           // [AtomiX]______

timer.start();                                              // [1]_____

for k in 0 .. n {
    s  = ( if k % 2 == 0 then 1.0 else -1.0 );     // (-1)^k
    x += s / ( 2.0 * k + 1.0 );
}

/* forall k in 0..n { AtomiX.add( ( if k % 2 == 0 then 1.0 else -1.0 )
                                / ( 2.0 * k + 1.0 )
                                  ); } */                   // [AtomiX]______

timer.stop();                                               // [2]_____
writeln( "time = ", timer.elapsed() );                      // [3]_____

   writef( "pi (approx) = %30.20dr\n", 4 * x );    
// writef( "pi (approx) = %30.20dr\n", 4 * AtimiX.read() ); // [AtomiX]______
// writef( "pi (exact)  = %30.20dr\n", pi );                // [4]_____

/*
--------------------------------------------------- [--fast] // AN EMPTY RUN
time = 1e-06

Real time:  9.582 s
User time:  8.479 s
Sys. time:  0.591 s
CPU share: 94.65 %
Exit code: 0
--------------------------------------------------- [--fast] // all commented

pi (approx) =         3.14159265458805059268

Real time: 15.553 s
User time: 13.484 s ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~> Timer ~ +/- 1 second ( O/S noise )
Sys. time:  0.985 s
CPU share: 93.03 %
Exit code: 0
-------------------------------------------------- [--fast ] // Timer-un-commented
time = 5.30128
time = 5.3329
pi (approx) =         3.14159265458805059268

Real time: 14.356 s
User time: 13.047 s ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~< Timer ~ +/- 1 second ( O/S noise )
Sys. time:  0.585 s
CPU share: 94.95 %
Exit code: 0

Real time: 16.804 s
User time: 14.853 s
Sys. time:  0.925 s
CPU share: 93.89 %
Exit code: 0

-------------------------------------------------- [--fast] // Timer-un-commented + forall + Atomics

time = 14.7406
pi (approx) =         3.14159265458805680993

Real time: 28.099 s
User time: 26.246 s
Sys. time: 0.914 s
CPU share: 96.65 %
Exit code: 0
*/
```

Comment: Thanks very much, so it seems it's a problem of my own environment or something... I will also try running it on my Linux machine later (because I have no access now).

Comment: O/S noise is an obvious enemy for any benchmarking for such a just tiny workload. Some re-runs may show this better, but the principal issues on a too noisy background remain.