# Does python's Pool() for parallelization prevent writing to global variables?

Tags: python-2.7, parallel-processing, global-variables, pool, parallelism-amdahl

In python 2.7 I am trying to distribute the computation of a two-dimensional array on all of the cores.
For that I have two arrays associated with a variable at the global scope, one to read from and one to write to.

```
import itertools as it
import multiprocessing as mp

temp_env = 20
c = 0.25
a = 0.02
arr = np.ones((100,100))
x = arr.shape[0]
y = arr.shape[1]
new_arr = np.zeros((x,y))

def calc_inside(idx):
    new_arr[idx[0],idx[1]] = (       arr[idx[0],  idx[1]  ]
                             + c * ( arr[idx[0]+1,idx[1]  ]
                                   + arr[idx[0]-1,idx[1]  ]
                                   + arr[idx[0],  idx[1]+1]
                                   + arr[idx[0],  idx[1]-1]
                                   - arr[idx[0],  idx[1]  ]*4
                                     )
                             - 2 * a
                                 * ( arr[idx[0],  idx[1]  ]
                                   - temp_env
                                     )
                               )

inputs = it.product( range( 1, x-1 ),
                     range( 1, y-1 )
                     )
p = mp.Pool()
p.map( calc_inside, inputs )

#for i in inputs:
#    calc_inside(i)

#plot arrays as surface plot to check values
```

Assume there is some additional initialization for the array `arr` with some different values other than that exemplary `1`-s, so that the computation ( an iterative calculation of the temperature ) actually makes a sense.

When I use the commented out `for`-loop, instead of the `Pool.map()` method, everything works fine and the array actually contains values. When using the `Pool()` function, the variable `new_array` just stays in its initialized state ( meaning it contains only the zeros, as it was originally initialised with ).

**Q1 :** Does that mean that `Pool()` prevents writing to global variables?

**Q2 :** Is there any other way to tackle this problem with parallelization?

Answer (score 0):

**A1 :**
your code actually does not use any variable declared using a syntax of **`global <variable>`**. Nevertheless, do not try to go into trying to use them, the less in going into distributed processing.

**A2 :**
Yes, going parallelised is possible, but better get a thorough sense of the costs of doing so, before spending ( well, wasting ) efforts, that never justify costs for doing so.

---

### Why starting about costs?

Will you pay your bank clerk an amount of $2.00 to receive just a $1.00 banknote in exchange?

Guess no one would ever do.

The same is with trying to go parallel.

Syntax is "**free**" and "**promising**",
Syntax costs of the actual execution of a simple and nicely-looking syntax-constructor **is not**. Expect rather shocking surprises instead of receiving any dinner for free.

---

### What are the actual costs? Benchmark. Benchmark. Benchmark!

**The useful work**
Your code actually does just a few memory accesses and a few floating point operations "inside" the block and exits. These FLOP-s take less than a few tens of **`[ns]`** max a few units of **`[us]`** on recent CPU frequencies ~ `2.6 ~ 3.4 [GHz]`. Do **[benchmark it:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47594399/3666197)**

```
from zmq import Stopwatch; aClk = Stopwatch()

temp_env = 20
c        =  0.25
a        =  0.02

aClk.start()
_ = ( 1.0
    + c * ( 1.0
          + 1.0
          + 1.0
          + 1.0
          - 1.0 * 4
            )
    - 2 * a
        * ( 1.0
          - temp_env
            )
      )
T = aClk.stop()
```

So, a pure **`[SERIAL]`**-process execution, on a Quad-core CPU, will not be worse than about a `T+T+T+T` ( having been executed one after another ).

```
         +-+-+-+--------------------------------- on CpuCore[0]
         : : : :
<start>| : : : :
       |T| : : :
       . |T| : :
       .   |T| :
       .     |T|
       .       |<stop>
       |<----->|
        = 4.T in a pure [SERIAL]-process schedule on CpuCore[0]
```

What will happen, if the same amount of **usefull work** will be enforced to happen inside some form of the now **`[CONCURRENT]`**-process execution ( using `multiprocessing.Pool`'s methods ), potentially using more CPU-cores for the same purpose?

The actual compute-phase, will not last less than **`T`** again, right? Why ever would it be? Yes, never.

```
                               A.......................B...............C.D Cpu[0]
<start>|                       :                       :               : :
       |<setup a subprocess[A]>|                       :               :
       .                       |                       :               
       .                       |<setup a subprocess[B]>|
       .                       | +............+........................... Cpu[!0]
       .                       | :            :        |
       .                       |T|            :        |
       .                         |<ret val(s) |        | +............+... Cpu[!0]
       .                         |   [A]->main|        | :            :
       .                                               |T|            :
       .                                                 |<ret val(s) |
       .                                                 |   [B]->main|
       .                                                                      
       .
       .                                                           ..   |<stop>
       |<--------------------------------------------------------- .. ->|
           i.e. >> 4.T ( while simplified, yet the message is clear )
```

**The overheads** <sup>i.e. the Costs you will always pay per-call ( and that is indeed many times )</sup>
Subprocess setup + termination **costs** ( **[benchmark it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47594399/3666197)** to learn the **scales of these cost** ). Memory access **costs** ( latency, where zero cache-re-use happens to help, as you exit ).

---

### Epilogue

Hope the visual message is clear enough to **ALWAYS** start accounting the accrued costs before deciding about any achievable benefits from going into re-engineering code into a distributed process-flow, having a multi-core or even many-core `[CONCURRENT]` fabric available.