# Why does the get() operation in multiprocessing.Pool.map_async take so long?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, parallelism-amdahl

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

pool   = mp.Pool( processes = 4 )
inp    = np.linspace( 0.01, 1.99, 100 )
result = pool.map_async( func, inp ) #Line1 ( func is some Python function which acts on input )
output = result.get()                #Line2
```

So, I was trying to parallelize some code in Python, using a **`.map_async()`** method on a `multiprocessing.Pool()` instance.

I noticed that while
`Line1` takes around a thousandth of a second,
`Line2` takes about .3 seconds.

Is there a better way to do this or a way to get around the bottleneck caused by `Line2`,
or
am I doing something wrong here?

<sub>( I am rather new to this. )</sub>

Comment: The `ap_async()` just starts the processing. The `get()` on the other hand has to wait until all processes have finished and have a result. What else did you expect to happen?

Comment: If your goal is to get results as they become available, rather than waiting for all tasks to complete, you'd typically iterate over the result of `imap` (or if you don't care about ordering, `imap_unordered` for extra speed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Am I doing something wrong here?*

### Do not panic, many users do the very same - Paid more than received.

This is a common lecture not on using some "*promising*" syntax-constructor, but on paying the actual costs for using it.

The story is long, the effect was straightforward - you expected a low hanging fruit, but had to pay an immense cost of process-instantiation, work-package re-distribution and for collection of results, all that circus just for doing but a few rounds of `func()`-calls.

---

### Wow?
Stop!
Parallelisation was brought to me that will SPEEDUP processing?!?

[Well, who told you that **any** such ( *potential* ) **speedup is for free?**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)

Let's be quantitative and rather measure the actual code-execution time, instead of emotions, right?

Benchmarking is always a fair move.
It helps us, mortals, to escape from just expectations
and get ourselves into quantitative records-of-evidence supported **knowledge**:

```
from zmq import Stopwatch; aClk = Stopwatch() # this is a handy tool to do so
```

---

### AS-IS test:

Before moving forwards, one ought record this pair:

```
>>> aClk.start(); _ = [   func( SEQi ) for SEQi in inp ]; aClk.stop() # [SEQ] 
>>> HowMuchWillWePAY2RUN( func, 4, 100 )                              # [RUN]
>>> HowMuchWillWePAY2MAP( func, 4, 100 )                              # [MAP]
```

This will set the span among the performance envelopes from a pure-[**`[SERIAL]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info) [SEQ]-of-calls, to an un-optimised `joblib.Parallel()` or any other, if one wishes to extend the experiment with any other tools, like a said  `multiprocessing.Pool()` or other.

---

### Test-case A:

**Intent:**
so as to measure the cost of a { process | job }-instantiation, we need a NOP-work-package payload, that will spend almost nothing "there" but return "back" and will not require to pay any additional add-on costs ( be it for any input parameters' transmissions or returning any value )

```
def a_NOP_FUN( aNeverConsumedPAR ):
    """                                                 __doc__
    The intent of this FUN() is indeed to do nothing at all,
                             so as to be able to benchmark
                             all the process-instantiation
                             add-on overhead costs.
    """
    pass
```

---

So, the setup-overhead add-on costs comparison is here:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------<function a_NOP_FUN
[SEQ]-pure-[SERIAL] worked within ~   37 ..     44 [us] on this localhost
[MAP]-just-[CONCURENT] tool         2536 ..   7343 [us]
[RUN]-just-[CONCURENT] tool       111162 .. 112609 [us]
```

---

### Using a strategy of
`joblib.delayed()` on `joblib.Parallel()` task-processing:

```
def HowMuchWillWePAY2RUN( aFun2TEST = a_NOP_FUN, JOBS_TO_SPAWN = 4, RUNS_TO_RUN = 10 ):
    from zmq import Stopwatch; aClk = Stopwatch()
    try:
         aClk.start()
         joblib.Parallel(  n_jobs = JOBS_TO_SPAWN
                          )( joblib.delayed( aFun2TEST )
                                           ( aFunPARAM )
                                       for ( aFunPARAM )
                                       in  range( RUNS_TO_RUN )
                             )
    except:
         pass
    finally:
         try:
             _ = aClk.stop()
         except:
             _ = -1
             pass
    pass;  pMASK = "CLK:: {0:_>24d} [us] @{1: >4d}-JOBs ran{2: >6d} RUNS {3:}"
    print( pMASK.format( _,
                         JOBS_TO_SPAWN,
                         RUNS_TO_RUN,
                         " ".join( repr( aFun2TEST ).split( " ")[:2] )
                         )
            )
```

---

### Using a strategy of a lightweight
`.map_async()` method on a `multiprocessing.Pool()` instance:

```
def HowMuchWillWePAY2MAP( aFun2TEST = a_NOP_FUN, PROCESSES_TO_SPAWN = 4, RUNS_TO_RUN = 1 ):
    from zmq import Stopwatch; aClk = Stopwatch()
    try:
         import numpy           as np
         import multiprocessing as mp

         pool = mp.Pool( processes = PROCESSES_TO_SPAWN )
         inp  = np.linspace( 0.01, 1.99, 100 )

         aClk.start()
         for i in xrange( RUNS_TO_RUN ):
             pass;    result = pool.map_async( aFun2TEST, inp )
             output = result.get()
         pass
    except:
         pass
    finally:
         try:
             _ = aClk.stop()
         except:
             _ = -1
             pass
    pass;  pMASK = "CLK:: {0:_>24d} [us] @{1: >4d}-PROCs ran{2: >6d} RUNS {3:}"
    print( pMASK.format( _,
                         PROCESSES_TO_SPAWN,
                         RUNS_TO_RUN,
                         " ".join( repr( aFun2TEST ).split( " ")[:2] )
                         )
            )
```

---

So,
the first set of pain and surprises
comes straight at the actual **cost-of-doing-NOTHING** in a concurrent pool of **`joblib.Parallel()`**:

```
 CLK:: __________________117463 [us] @   4-JOBs ran    10 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________111182 [us] @   3-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________110229 [us] @   3-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________110095 [us] @   3-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________111794 [us] @   3-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________110030 [us] @   3-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________110697 [us] @   3-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: _________________4605843 [us] @ 123-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________336208 [us] @ 123-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________298816 [us] @ 123-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________355492 [us] @ 123-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________320837 [us] @ 123-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________308365 [us] @ 123-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________372762 [us] @ 123-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________304228 [us] @ 123-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________337537 [us] @ 123-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________941775 [us] @ 123-JOBs ran 10000 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: __________________987440 [us] @ 123-JOBs ran 10000 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: _________________1080024 [us] @ 123-JOBs ran 10000 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: _________________1108432 [us] @ 123-JOBs ran 10000 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
 CLK:: _________________7525874 [us] @ 123-JOBs ran100000 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN
```

So, this scientifically fair and rigorous test started from this **simplest ever case**, already showing the benchmarked costs of all the associated code-execution processing setup-overheads **a smallest ever** `joblib.Parallel()` **penalty sine-qua-non**.

This forwards us into a direction, where real-world algorithms do live - best with next adding some larger and larger "payload"-sizes into the testing loop.

---

### Now, we know the penalty
for going into a ["*just*"-`[CONCURRENT]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info) code-execution - and next?

Using this systematic and lightweight approach, we may go forwards in the story, as we will need to also benchmark the add-on costs and other Amdahl's Law indirect effects of `{ remote-job-PAR-XFER(s) | remote-job-MEM.alloc(s) | remote-job-CPU-bound-processing | remote-job-fileIO(s) }`

A function template like this may help in re-testing ( as you see there will be a lot to re-run, while the O/S noise and some additional artifacts will step into the actual cost-of-use patterns ):

---

### Test-case B:

Once we have paid the up-front cost, the next most common mistake is to forget the costs of memory allocations. So, lets test it:

```
def a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR( aNeverConsumedPAR, SIZE1D = 1000 ):
    """                                                 __doc__
    The intent of this FUN() is to do nothing but
                             a MEM-allocation
                             so as to be able to benchmark
                             all the process-instantiation
                             add-on overhead costs.
    """
    import numpy as np              # yes, deferred import, libs do defer imports
    aMemALLOC = np.zeros( ( SIZE1D, #       so as to set
                            SIZE1D, #       realistic ceilings
                            SIZE1D, #       as how big the "Big Data"
                            SIZE1D  #       may indeed grow into
                            ),
                          dtype = np.float64,
                          order = 'F'
                          )         # .ALLOC + .SET
    aMemALLOC[2,3,4,5] = 8.7654321  # .SET
    aMemALLOC[3,3,4,5] = 1.2345678  # .SET

    return aMemALLOC[2:3,3,4,5]
```

In case your platform will stop to be able to allocate the requested memory-blocks, there we head-bang into another kind of problems ( with a class of hidden glass-ceilings if trying to go-parallel in a physical-resources agnostic manner ). One may edit the `SIZE1D` scaling, so as to at least fit into the platform RAM addressing / sizing capabilites, yet, the performance envelopes of the real-world problem computing are still of our great interest here:

```
>>> HowMuchWillWePAY2RUN( a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR, 200, 1000 )
```

may yield
**a cost-to-pay,** being anything between **`0.1 [s]` and `+9 [s]`** (!!)
**just for doing STILL NOTHING**, but now also **without forgetting** about some realistic MEM-allocation **add-on costs "*there*"**

```
CLK:: __________________116310 [us] @   4-JOBs ran    10 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________120054 [us] @   4-JOBs ran    10 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________129441 [us] @  10-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________123721 [us] @  10-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________127126 [us] @  10-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________124028 [us] @  10-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________305234 [us] @ 100-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________243386 [us] @ 100-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________241410 [us] @ 100-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________267275 [us] @ 100-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________244207 [us] @ 100-JOBs ran   100 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________653879 [us] @ 100-JOBs ran  1000 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________405149 [us] @ 100-JOBs ran  1000 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________351182 [us] @ 100-JOBs ran  1000 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________362030 [us] @ 100-JOBs ran  1000 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: _________________9325428 [us] @ 200-JOBs ran  1000 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________680429 [us] @ 200-JOBs ran  1000 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________533559 [us] @ 200-JOBs ran  1000 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: _________________1125190 [us] @ 200-JOBs ran  1000 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
CLK:: __________________591109 [us] @ 200-JOBs ran  1000 RUNS <function a_NOP_FUN_WITH_JUST_A_MEM_ALLOCATOR
```

### Test-case C:

kindly [read the tail sections of **this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551850/training-a-few-sklearn-models-in-a-joblib-parallel-n-jobs-4-blocks-the/47560341#47560341)

### Test-case D:

kindly [read the tail sections of **this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551850/training-a-few-sklearn-models-in-a-joblib-parallel-n-jobs-4-blocks-the/47560341#47560341)

---

### Epilogue:

For each and every "promise", the fair best next step is first to cross-validate the actual code-execution costs, before starting any code re-engineering. The sum of real-world platform's add-on costs may devastate any expected speedups, even if the original, overhead-naive Amdahl's Law might have created some expected speedup-effects.

As Mr. Walter E. Deming has expressed many times, **without DATA we make ourselves left to just OPINIONS**.

---

<sub>A bonus part:

having read as far as here, one might already found, that there is not any kind of "drawback" or "error" in the `#Line2` per se, but the carefull design practice will show any better syntax-constructor, that spend less to achieve more ( as actual resources ( CPU, MEM, IOs, O/S ) permit on the code-execution platform ). Anything else is not principally different from a just blind telling Fortune.</sub>