# pathos: parallel processing options - Could someone explain the differences?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pathos, parallelism-amdahl

I am trying to run parallel processes under python (on ubuntu).

I started using multiprocessing and it worked fine for simple examples.
Then came the pickle error, and so I switched to pathos. I got a little confused with the different options and so wrote a very simple benchmarking code.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from pathos.multiprocessing import Pool as Pool1
from pathos.pools import ParallelPool as Pool2
from pathos.parallel import ParallelPool as Pool3
import time

def square(x):  
    # calculate the square of the value of x
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':

    dataset = range(0,10000)

    start_time = time.time()
    for d in dataset:
        square(d)
    print('test with no cores: %s seconds' %(time.time() - start_time))

    nCores = 3
    print('number of cores used: %s' %(nCores))  


    start_time = time.time()

    p = mp.Pool(nCores)
    p.map(square, dataset)

    # Close
    p.close()
    p.join()

    print('test with multiprocessing: %s seconds' %(time.time() - start_time))


    start_time = time.time()

    p = Pool1(nCores)
    p.map(square, dataset)

    # Close
    p.close()
    p.join()

    print('test with pathos multiprocessing: %s seconds' %(time.time() - start_time))


    start_time = time.time()

    p = Pool2(nCores)
    p.map(square, dataset)

    # Close
    p.close()
    p.join()

    print('test with pathos pools: %s seconds' %(time.time() - start_time))


    start_time = time.time()

    p = Pool3()
    p.ncpus = nCores
    p.map(square, dataset)

    # Close
    p.close()
    p.join()

    print('test with pathos parallel: %s seconds' %(time.time() - start_time))
```

I get about
- 0.001s with plain serial code, without parallel,
- 0.100s with `multiprocessing` option,
- 0.100s with `pathos.multiprocessing`,
- 4.470s with `pathos.pools`,
- an `AssertionError` error with `pathos.parallel`

I copied how to use these various options from http://trac.mystic.cacr.caltech.edu/project/pathos/browser/pathos/examples.html

I understand that parallel processing is longer than a plain serial code for such a simple example. What I do not understand is the relative performance of pathos.

I checked discussions, but could not understand why `pathos.pools` is so much longer, and why I get an error (not sure then what the performance of that last option would be).

I also tried with a simple square function, and for that even `pathos.multiprocessing` is much longer than `multiprocessing`

Could someone explain the differences between these various options?

Additionally, I ran the `pathos.multiprocessing` option on a remote computer, running centOS, and performance is about **10 times worse** than `multiprocessing`.

According to company renting the computer, it should work just like a home computer. I understand that it will, maybe, be difficult to provide info without more details on the machine, but if you have any ideas as to where it could come from, that would help.

Comment: Original URL seemed not to be publicly accessible ( 404 Not Found / Code: NoSuchKey ). For implementation details, may review the source-code or ask Mike McKearns ( was active on StackOverflow too ).

Comment: @user3666197 - We've received complaints about your use of bizarre formatting in editing other posts (use of inappropriate boldface, [SERIAL] instead of serial, etc.). I've removed that formatting here. Please don't impose your own non-standard style on other posts here.

Comment: @BradLarson Yes, you remove any content you decide to. **Would you help in disambiguation** - what formatting seems to you to be reasonably acceptable for making a difference between the **(A)** plain text with a word "parallel" ( used in a common, often professionally agnostic speech ) and **(B)** a computer science terminology term [PARALLEL], which does have a one and only one, very particular meaning, not allowing any other but this very exact C/S-context from theory of systems for one, unique, type of process scheduling? I add cross-references for this very purpose ( if you've noticed ).

Comment: @user3666197 - I think it's pretty clear what parallel and serial mean in various contexts. I don't see a need to unilaterally apply formatting to posts that no one else uses. All that will do is further distract people from the content. Before taking actions on your own, perhaps you should ask the community at [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) whether they support it. If they do, I'd be happy to let it stay. At present, however, people are angry you're doing this and are complaining to moderators about it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm the `pathos` author.  Sorry for the confusion.  You are dealing with a mix of the old and new programming interface.

The "new" (suggested) interface is to use `pathos.pools`.  The old interface links to the same objects, so it's really two ways to get to the same thing.

`multiprocess.Pool` is a fork of `multiprocessing.Pool`, with the only difference being that `multiprocessing` uses `pickle` and `multiprocess` uses `dill`.  So, I'd expect the speed to be the same in most simple cases.

The above pool can also be found at `pathos.pools._ProcessPool`.  `pathos` provides a small wrapper around several types of pools, with different backends, giving an extended functionality.  The `pathos`-wrapped pool is `pathos.pools.ProcessPool` (and the old interface provides it at `pathos.multiprocessing.Pool`).

The preferred interface is `pathos.pools.ProcessPool`.

There's also the `ParallelPool`, which uses a different backend -- it uses `ppft` instead of `multiprocess`.  `ppft` is "parallel python" which spawns python processes through `subprocess` and passes source code (with `dill.source` instead of serialized objects) -- it's intended for distributed computing, or when passing by source code is a better option.

So, `pathos.pools.ParallelPool` is the preferred interface, and `pathos.parallel.ParallelPool` (and a few other similar references in `pathos`) are hanging around for legacy reasons -- but they are the same object underneath.

In summary:

```
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> mp.Pool()
<multiprocessing.pool.Pool object at 0x10fa6b6d0>
>>> import multiprocess as mp
>>> mp.Pool()
<multiprocess.pool.Pool object at 0x11000c910>
>>> import pathos as pa
>>> pa.pools._ProcessPool()
<multiprocess.pool.Pool object at 0x11008b0d0>
>>> pa.multiprocessing.Pool()
<multiprocess.pool.Pool object at 0x11008bb10>
>>> pa.pools.ProcessPool()
<pool ProcessPool(ncpus=4)>
>>> pa.pools.ParallelPool()
<pool ParallelPool(ncpus=*, servers=None)>
```

You can see the `ParallelPool` has `servers`... thus is intended for distributed computing.

The only remaining question is why the `AssertionError`?  Well that is because the wrapper that `pathos` adds keeps a pool object available for reuse.  Hence, when you call the `ParallelPool` a second time, you are calling a closed pool.  You'd need to `restart` the pool to enable it to be used again.

```
>>> f = lambda x:x
>>> p = pa.pools.ParallelPool()
>>> p.map(f, [1,2,3])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> p.close()
>>> p.join()
>>> p.restart()  # throws AssertionError w/o this
>>> p.map(f, [1,2,3])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> p.close()
>>> p.join()
>>> p.clear()  # destroy the saved pool
```

The `ProcessPool` has the same interface as `ParallelPool`, with respect to restarting and clearing saved instances.

Comment: can We have multiple servers using pathos? any examples for that?

Comment: `pathos.ParallelPool` is built on `ppft`, and uses `servers` the same way as `ppft`.  Check in the `pathos/examples` folder, for example: https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/blob/master/examples/test_ppmap2.py.

Comment: Hello @MikeMcKerns, I have been trying to use `pathos`, but I am getting this `TypeError: can't pickle _cffi_backend.FFI objects` error. Any idea on how to solve this pickle issue?

Comment: @TonyMontana: are you getting a pickle-related error with `ppft` (`ParallelPool`) or `multiprocess` (`ProcessPool`)?  It should not happen from the former.  There are many reasons that an object can be unpicklable, you should open a ticket on GitHub and address this (as opposed to in the comments here).

Answer (score 3):

### Could someone explain the differences?

Let's start from some common ground.

Python interpreter uses, as standard, a GIL-stepped code-execution. This means, that all **thread**-based pools still do wait for a GIL-stepped ordering of all code-execution paths, so **any** such constructed attempt **will not enjoy** benefits " *theoretically expected* ".

Python interpreter may use other, **process**-based instances for loading multiple process, each having its own GIL-lock, forming a pool of multiple, concurrent code-execution paths.

Having managed this principal dis-ambiguation, the performance-related questions start to appear next. The most responsible approach is to benchmark, benchmark, **benchmark**. No exception here.

---

### What does it take so much time to spend here ( where )?

Major ( **constant** ) part is a primarily **`[TIME]`**-domain cost of a process-instantiation. Here, the complete replica of python interpreter, including all variables, all memory-maps, indeed a complete state-full-copy of the calling python interpreter has to be first created and placed onto the operating system process-scheduler table, before any further ( useful part of the job ) computing "inside" such successfully instantiated sub-process can take place. If your payload function just immediately returns from there, having created an **`x*x`**, your code seems to have burnt all that fuel for a few CPU-instructions and you have spent way more than received in return. **Economy of costs** goes against you, as all the process-instantiation plus process-termination costs are way higher than a few CPU-CLOCK ticks.

**How long does this actually take?**
You can benchmark this ( as proposed **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551850/training-a-few-sklearn-models-in-a-joblib-parallel-n-jobs-4-blocks-the/47560341#47560341)**, in a proposed **`Test-Case-A`**. If `Stopwatch()`-ed **`[us]`** decide, you start to rely on facts more than on any sorts of wannabe-guru or marketing type of advice. That's fair, isn't it? ).

---

### `Test-Case-A` benchmarks process-instantiation costs [MEASURED].
What next?

The next most dangerous ( **variable** in size ) part is a primarily **`[SPACE]`**-domain costs, yet having also the `[TIME]`-domain impact, if `[SPACE]`-allocation costs start to grow beyond small footprint scales.

This sort of add-on overhead costs is related to any need to pass "large"-sized parameters, from the "main"-python interpreter to each and every of the ( distributed ) sub-process instances.

**How long does this take?**
Again, benchmark, benchmark, benchmark. Shall benchmark this ( as proposed **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551850/training-a-few-sklearn-models-in-a-joblib-parallel-n-jobs-4-blocks-the/47560341#47560341)**, if extending a there proposed **`Test-Case-C`** with a replacement of **`aNeverConsumedPAR`** parameter with some indeed "fat"-chunk of data, be it a **`numpy.ndarray()`** or other type, bearing some huge memory-footprint. )

This way, the real hardware-related + O/S-related + python-related data-flow costs start to become visible and measured in such a benchmark as additional overhead costs in `**[us]**`. This is nothing new to ol' hackers, yet, people who never met that an HDD-disk-write times could grow into and block other processing for **many seconds or minutes** would hardly believe, if not touching by one's own benchmarking the real costs of data-flow. So, do not hesitate to **extend the benchmark `Test-Case-C` to indeed large memory-footprints to smell the smoke ...**

---

### Last, but not least, the re-formulated Amdahl's Law will tell ...

given an attempt to parallelise some computation is well understood both as per the computing part and also as per all the overhead-part(s), the picture starts to get complete:

The [**overhead-strict and resources-aware Amdahl's Law** re-formulation](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) shows:

```
                           1                         
S =  ______________________________________________ ;  where         s,
                    /                     \                    ( 1 - s ),
                   |  ( 1 - s )            |                       pSO,
     s  + pSO + max|  _________ , atomicP  |  + pTO                pTO,
                   |      N                |                         N
                    \                     /           have been defined in
                                                      just an Overhead-strict Law
and
atomicP := is a further indivisible duration of an atomic-process-block
```

That the resulting speedup **`S`** will **always suffer** from high overhead costs **`pSO + pTO`** the same as when whatever high **`N`** will not be allowed to further help, because of a high enough value of **`atomicP`**.

In all these cases the **final speedup `S`** may easily **fall under `<< 1.0`**, yes, well under a pure-**`[SERIAL]`** code-execution path schedule ( again, having benchmarked the real costs of **`pSO`** and **`pTO`** ( for which the Test-Case-A + Test-Case-C ( *extended* ) was schematically proposed ) there comes a chance to derive the minimum reasonable computing-payload needed so as to remain above the mystic level of a Speedup **`>= 1.0`**

Comment: Thanks @user3666197 for the general info and benchmarking tips. My question was more about the differences in performance between `multiprocessing` and the `pathos` functions.

Comment: Seems that I did not understand your point in this comment. There are no pieces of ***general information*** in the Answer, but steps how to measure the components of the said **differences in performance**. So, if you run the proposed A/B testing on your platform on your code, the quantitative results will explain you both the scale + the origin of such **differences in performance**. Knowing **why** is always more important than just passively observing that **it happened to be so slow** ( but having no clue why ). Good luck with the right technology for indeed **[tag:parallel-processing]**

Comment: Thanks, I will do that to choose the best process for my code. The intention was to try to understand the intention behind having `pathos.multiprocessing`, `pathos.pools`, and `pathos.parallel`. These different options must have been designed with different use cases in mind? I cannot find any information on that.

Comment: Benchmarking will deliver you the answers. Setup + Termination overhead-costs benchmark Test-Case-s will tell you when ( not ) use each of them. Similarly the CPU-bound payload benchmark Test-Case-D + some heavy disk/network activity IO-bound payload based Test-Case-X will demystify the realistic workload / performance landscapes of each of the test-bed setup, which is what you wanted to get, right? So, keep testing and you touch the very truth - no marketing, no dogmatic slogan, no skewed "best practice", the naked facts about how things actually work + you learn darn lot on doing this well.